# Rspec generated spec failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I've added the following to my application.rb file

```
config.generators do |g|
    g.test_framework :rspec,

        :fixtures => true,
        :view_specs => false,
        :helper_specs => false,
        :routing_specs => false,
        :controller_specs => true,
        :request_specs => true

    g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, :dir => "spec/factories"
end
```

Then I generated a controller with

```
$rails g controller home index
```

This generated the specification in spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb which looks like this

```
describe HomeController do

  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'index'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

end
```

This is the default code generated by rSpec. I can see the page when I visit

```
http://localhost:3000/home/index
```

in my browser

Then when I run

```
$bundle exec rspec
```

I get this error

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/2012/myapp/spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant HomeController (NameError)
from /Users/bobwood/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load'
from /Users/bobwood/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /Users/bobwood/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `map'
from /Users/bobwood/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load_spec_files'
from /Users/bobwood/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from /Users/bobwood/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
from /Users/bobwood/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

What does this error mean and how to I fix it?

EDIT: routes.rb has one line in it

```
get "home/index"
```

Comment: What does your routes file look like?

Comment: Added routes.rb in edit above

Comment: actually reading Matts answer he is correct, looks like you are making it more difficult than it needs to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that the spec file you run doesn't know about your `HomeController` class - it's not included.

I think you chose a more difficult way to use RSpec in Rails. The easiest way is to use [rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails). I looked into my controller specs and the first thing they do is to include `rspec_helper.rb`, which comes from rspec-rails. I guess this file is used to load all the Rails classes you need for your test.

To install rspec-rails all you need to do is add it to your Gemfile and run:

`rails generate rspec:install`